# How do handle interpolation when input is out of scope?

Tags: matlab

Let's say, I need to do this interpolation

```
  z = 1:1:240;
  x = 0.1:0.1:1;
  phi_1 = [0.02, 0.08, 0.17, 0.27, 0.38, 0.45, 0.67, 0.74, 0.86, 1.0];
  zz= z/240;
  phi_z = interp1(x, phi_1, zz);
```

The problem, is that when `zz < 0.1`, there is no data for it.
And in this case, I want it stick to the `x = 0.1, phi_1 = 0.02`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `interp1` function offers a 4th input argument for the interpolation (and extrapolation) method, the default is `'linear'`, and also a 5th input argument for extrapolation cases. This argument can be a string: `'extrap'`, matlab then will apply the specified method also for extrapolation cases. The input can also be a constant value `extrapval`, that value will be returned for any input out of scope. 
So, in this example, you simply want to set the extrapolation value `extrapval` to `phi_1(1)`.

```
z = 1:1:240;
x = 0.1:0.1:1;
phi_1 = [0.02, 0.08, 0.17, 0.27, 0.38, 0.45, 0.67, 0.74, 0.86, 1.0];
zz= z/240;
phi_z = interp1(x, phi_1, zz, 'linear', phi_1(1)); %// set extrapolation value
```

The grapical representation then looks like this:

```
plot(x, phi_1, 'ko')
hold on
plot(zz, phi_z, 'r-')
legend('data', 'interpolation and constant extrapolation')
```

[image]
Notice the constant extrapolation for values lower than 0.1 (on the left hand side).

This is how it **should** be done, but it does not seem too robust to me. Consider the case, where you wanted `zz=0:0.01:1.1`, so you extrapolate in both directions. There a **single** constant extrapolation value does not make too much sense to me. Guddus solution seems to be more robust, especially if you add something like: `phi_z(zz > max(x)) = phi_1(end);` for the extrapolation cases in the other direction.

Answer (score 1):

add one more line

```
phi_z(zz<min(x))=phi_1(1);
```